# How to interpret the results of a Bayesian GLM logistic regression?

Tags: regression, bayesian, logistic, interpretation

I'm running a Bayesian GLM logistic regression because a traditional GLM reported perfect separation issues. However, I'm new to this type of regression and I'm not sure how to interpret coefficients here. Is there a way to know which coefficients are significant as in a normal logistic regression? In my original model I'm trying to identify a U-shaped relationship between Y and X. How can I know if such relationship is there and significant?

```
                 coef.est coef.se
(Intercept)      -0.15     3.48  
Control1         -4.38     6.14  
Control2         -3.46     8.01  
Control3          0.19     0.27  
Control4          0.00     0.02  
Control5          0.72     0.36  
Control6          0.03     0.19  
Control7         -1.39     2.14  
Control8          0.59     1.18  
Control9          0.38     0.50  
as.factor(SIC1)2  0.38     1.18  
as.factor(SIC1)3 -0.12     1.25  
as.factor(SIC1)4  0.52     1.44  
as.factor(SIC1)5  0.10     1.20  
as.factor(SIC1)6 -0.33     1.12  
as.factor(SIC1)7  0.34     1.99  
as.factor(SIC1)8 -1.51     1.21  
X                -3.19     1.42  
X^2               0.35     0.21 
---
n = 61, k = 19
residual deviance = 35.2, null deviance = 57.6 (difference = 22.4)
```